# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I want to extract the file field from my model and open the file (the file is in .pdf format). but I got this error :

> expected str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not QuerySet

**my models.py is:**

```
class FileUpload(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True , null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

**my views.py is:**

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = "object_list"
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

    def get_object(self, *args,**kwargs):
        request = self.request
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        instance = FileUpload.objects.filter(id = pk)

        if instance is None:
            raise Http404("File Does not EXIST")
        else:
            pdfFileObj = open(instance, 'rb')
            pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
            print(pdfReader.numPages)
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
            print(pageObj.extractText())
            pdfFileObj.close()
        return instance
```

Right now I am not using any template. Just want to print the file data inside my terminal. Mean when I refresh the page I got this error.

Comment: actually, you are using instance need a file path

Comment: just do
pdfFileObj = open(instance.file.path, 'rb')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're working with a queryset rather than an instance of your model.

```
instance = FileUpload.objects.filter(id=pk)
```

`.filter(..)` returns a queryset. What you want here is `.get(id=pk)` to get a single instance of your model.

```
instance = FileUpload.objects.get(id=pk)
```

But you still have another issue which is treating a model instance like a file. You'll need to access the field of the instance:

```
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(instance.file)
```

Comment: I rejected an edit here that opens the file on a separate line as I don't think it's required. Passing the `file` field *should* be enough, as it can be opened by the Pdf reader.